# Error Request failed with status code 400

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to create sitemap with nuxtjs:

```
sitemap: {
        hostname: process.env.BASE_URL,
        zip: true,
        i18n: {
            locales: ['en', 'fa'],
            routesNameSeparator: '___'
        },
        defaults: {
            changefreq: 'daily',
            priority: 1,
            lastmod: new Date()
        },
        sitemaps: [
            {
                path: '/fa/sitemap/products.xml',
                routes: async () => {

                    /* axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
                        // Do something before request is sent
                        return config;
                    }, function (error) {
                        // Do something with request error
                        console.log(error);
                        process.sentry.captureException(new Error(error))
                        return Promise.reject(error);
                    }); */

                    const URL = `${process.env.API_URL}${process.env.API_PREFIX}`;
                    const products = await axios.get(`${URL}/sitemap?query=products`, {
                        headers: {locale: 'fa'}
                    })
                        .then((r) => {
                            // console.log(r);
                            return r && r.data.result
                        })

                    return products.map((product) => {
                        return {
                            url: `/fa/product/${product.id}/${decodeURIComponent(product.slug)}`,
                            changefreq: 'daily',
                            priority: 1,
                            lastmod: product.last_modified_at
                        }
                    })
                },
                exclude: ['/**']
            },
```

but when I deploy on server I got this error message:

```
ERROR Request failed with status code 400
at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)                                                                                
at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)                                                                                           
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:293:11)                                                               
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:388:22)                                                                                                        
at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1336:12)                                                                                           
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)                                                                              
ERROR  Request failed with status code 400                                                                                                        
at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)                                                                                 
at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)                                                                                           
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:293:11)                                                               
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:388:22)                                                                                                        
at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1336:12)                                                                                           
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

Comment: The code crashes, because a bad formed request was made. Can you confirm that there isn't an error in the `URL` variable? (Also on server side as well)

Comment: You can also check the backend or try that in Postman to see if it is in the correct format.